# How to write regex for Jenkins email ext ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX)

Tags: regex, jenkins

We're using the email-ext plugin with ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX) in the body.

The default regex which works well is:

```
 "(?i)\b(error|exception|fatal|fail(ed|ure)|un(defined|resolved))\b".
```

However, we have some java files that contain the word **Exception** and compiling them results in a bunch of lines in our email notification even though the build works.

Is there a way I can include the above but exclude anything that looks like:

```
/exception
```

The lines/files that are causing the problem contain the path to the java file so they all start with "/Exception"

Here is an excerpt of test string

```
src/com/somename/exceptions/XZeroLength.java 

src/com/somename/refdata/Exception.java
```

Comment: String to test?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/Fb1nQS/4

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi  - added test string to question

Comment: thanks, I think that will work!

Comment: Unfortunately any regex I try other than the default shows no results

Comment: I have zero exposure to jenkins, I just know a little bit of Regex. So if you can give me 4-5 lines of patterns that you want to match and 2-3 lines of patterns that should not match, I might be able to help you out. I'll suggest that you rephrase and post a new question or go to Java chatroom and point them here.